# Search in pdf and babel

Tags: pdftex, pdf, babel, font-encodings, ukrainian

I noticed that in my `PDF`-files search does not work if there is an `ukrainian`  letter "i" in the word.
Nevertheless, the search is works well in the words with the two other specific for `ukrainian language` letters "є" and "ї".

As you can see below, the

```
\input{glyphtounicode}
\pdfgentounicode=1
```

are included in preamble.

Is there is problem with the `babel`?

```
\documentclass[twoside]{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T2A,T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[ukrainian]{babel}
\input{glyphtounicode}
\pdfgentounicode=1
\begin{document}
ііііі\\
ффффф\\
їїїїїї\\
єєєєє
\end{document}
```

---

I compile with `miktex's` `Pdflatex`.

With `XeLaTeX` this problem does not appear.

---

Comment: There is no CYRILLIC SMALL LETTER BYELORUSSIAN-UKRAINIAN I in the T2A encoding; the UTF-8 character is translated into `\cyrii` that's in turn changed to `\char"69`, which is the Latin “i”.

Comment: @egreg What is the best encoding for ukrainian?

Comment: @egreg I found that with OT2 problem disappears. May be, it is better to use it? What problems can be with it?

Comment: No, OT2 is not an answer.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The T2A encoding idea predates PDF and Unicode support; in order to save a slot and accommodate as many languages as possible, the CYRILLIC SMALL LETTER BYELORUSSIAN-UKRAINIAN I and its uppercase variant are rendered using the Latin i and I present in the encoding table.

There's nothing `glyphtounicode` can do about it, because the letter that's output *is* the Latin letter.

However, for PDF viewers supporting the feature, `accsupp` can help:

```
\input{glyphtounicode}
\pdfgentounicode=1
\documentclass[twoside]{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T2A,T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[ukrainian]{babel}
\usepackage{accsupp}

\DeclareTextCommand{\cyrii}{T2A}{%
  \BeginAccSupp{method=hex,unicode,ActualText=0456}%
  \symbol{105}%
  \EndAccSupp{}%
}
\DeclareTextCommand{\CYRII}{T2A}{%
  \BeginAccSupp{method=hex,unicode,ActualText=0406}%
  \symbol{73}%
  \EndAccSupp{}%
}


\begin{document}
ііііі\\
ффффф\\
їїїїїї\\
єєєєє
\end{document}
```

If you view the output with Adobe Reader, the first row will be composed by U+0456 characters. Other PDF viewers may not have the necessary feature.

Comment: Its work, thanx!

Comment: Now `\hyphenation { пі-ра-мі-да }` does not work for me.

Comment: @brownian Sorry, but `accsupp` interferes with hyphenation. Nothing can be done about this, unfortunately. Switch to XeLaTeX or LuaLaTeX, using fonts with the real characters.