# Pdf search for ukrainian "і" and ї" letters

Tags: fonts, xetex, polyglossia, cyrillic, ukrainian

I am trying to make PDF in ukrainian language with proper search for letters "і", "Ї", "є".

I have tried [this](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/222063/search-in-pdf-and-babel) and xelatex. Both identify "і", "Ї" as **the same letters** during the search!

Is there any way to fix this?

Complete code representing the problem compiled with xelatex in Overleaf:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,14pt]{extarticle}

\usepackage{fontspec}
\usepackage{polyglossia}
\setdefaultlanguage{ukrainian}
\setotherlanguages{english,russian}
\setmainfont{Times New Roman}
\newfontfamily{\cyrillicfont}{Times New Roman}
\newfontfamily{\cyrillicfontsf}{Times New Roman}
\newfontfamily{\cyrillicfonttt}{Times New Roman}

\begin{document}
і і і

ї ї ї
\end{document}
```

In the resulting PDF after ctrl+F search for і and ї shows 6 results instead of 3 using Chrome viewer. Using latest acrobat reader it highlights all letters.

[image]

Comment: Are you sure it isn't an issue with your PDF viewer? I compiled your file, searched the "і" (single point) and no double-dot і's have appeared in the results.

Comment: I have tried it both: in Chrome and Acrobat reader. Both latest version. Problem still occurs.
What reader do you use?

Comment: Show a small, complete example. That makes it much easier to test your issue.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer I edited the post. Thanks.

Comment: In evince (Ubuntu 18.04) and Firefox only three results appear. Probably it is a PDF viewer issue.

Comment: The glyphs have clearly different to-unicode-values in the pdf. If the viewer decides to handle them as the same glyph there is not much you can do about it.

Answer (score 2):

I have tried to view with an Okular. Letters are distinguished correctly.

It is indeed viewer problem as mentioned in the comments